# Spring boot application is getting shutdown for non webapp application

Tags: spring-boot

I want to build a application which is not an web application using spring boot.

I'm using apache qpid jars to connect to service bus queue, and my application is consumer to the queue.

I'm using following dependency in my application, my application is not a web app and hence I'm removing the tomcat dependency. My app is packaged as jar.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
           <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

My application runs fine, but it's getting shutdown by itself.

Any idea on what am I missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: If it isn't a web app, then why do you have the `spring-boot-starter-web` as a dependency? If there is no proces stopping the application from shutting down (like a listener on a queue etc) then yes it will stop quite quickly.

Comment: I have created a jms message listener and my understanding is unless/until I close the connection my application will always be listening(consuming) message from the queue, but my application it self getting closed :(..  with below                                                 s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@5387f9e0: startup date [Tue Dec 13 07:35:22 EST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase

Comment: If you only have a listener and haven't properly configured your container to continue to listen it will shutdown.

Comment: As mentioned above, you dont need the web dependency.  It depends on how you have configured your app, but have a look at this question about a long running AMQP spring boot app - the answer includes an example of listener container code that should resolve the issue (caveat: depending on your application config) : http://stackoverflow.com/q/33467956/258813

Comment: I checked the stackoverflow link provide... I'm not using Rabbitmq, so I'm not able to use the full functionality i.e. so I can't use it though :(. Using jndi (qpid) api for connection.